# How to take relative path in c# window application?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to take relative path in c# window application, when i am running exe file?

This is my file path

```
C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\File_Uploading\File_Uploading\bin\Debug\File\img.png
```

Thans=ks

Comment: If you, say, execute `File.ReadLines("somefile")`, then it's read from the same directory where `exe` file is located.

Comment: use `Application.StartupPath`

Comment: Thank you for your help Actually, i need  to read file from project not full path

Comment: how can you read file from project without knowing it's full path?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by below code
    `string Imgpath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName + "\\File\\img.png";`

Comment: Thank you for your help Actually, i need  to read file from project not full path

Comment: is your file in the project directory or in another place? and is it a text file?

Comment: It's in project directory and it's image file

Comment: I am getting error like this when running my project exe    
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Desktop\File\im_3.jpg'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Can you help on this error ?

I am getting error like this when running my project exe    
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Desktop\File\im_3.jpg'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Comment: I have reupdated answer please check it once.

Comment: Still i am getting same error System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Debug\File\im_3.jpg'.
Here is my code 

  string appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string targetPath = appdata + @"\Microsoft\Signatures";
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, "im_3.jpg");
string Imgpath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName + "\\Debug\\File\\im_3.jpg";
System.IO.File.Copy(Imgpath, destFile, true);

When i am running project has exe

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do? your code is very confusing.

Comment: No, folder is not in desktop its in project folder
C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\File_Uploading\File_Uploading\bin\Debug\File

Comment: My requirement is copy file from one folder to another folder(without open dialog) in c# winform, when i am running as exe file i am getting above error.

Comment: string target = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\KeyPreview.PNG";
 string targetPath = 
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
 File.Copy(target,destFile);

Please use this code to achieve your requirement. in this case your image will copy to desktop

Comment: One clarification, When i am taking exe file, where will be this path deployed
C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\File_Uploading\File_Uploading\bin\Debug\File\img.png

Comment: where ever you put this .exe it will relate to that folder.

Comment: Were I need put my folder File\i‌​mg.png common, so i can run in different system.

Comment: can't get you can you please elaborate?

Comment: I no need to put in desktop and it should be in exe

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
string relativePathToImage = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "File", "img.png");
```

This is the path to 'img.png' inside the 'File' folder beneath your .exe file. You will need to include (using) System.IO

Comment: I am getting error like this when running my project exe See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box. ************** Exception Text ************** System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Desktop\File\im_3.jpg'. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Comment: Does the image

C:\Users\SH-PC-W10-17-7\Desktop\File\im_3.jpg

exist? On your desktop should be a folder called 'File' and inside the file 'im_3.jpg'

Comment: No, how to take when exe is running ?

Comment: I don't know, why you are asking then. When there is no picture in this location, you will always get these error